# Thingworx Composer not loading

Tags: linux, thingworx

I am trying to set up thingworx composer on a Linux machine.

In the Application logs the Server is ON and db is initialized.

But when in the browser I try to open composer, then it is stuck at the landing page (the black page with Thingworx logo in green) and doesn't go to the Composer Home page.

Comment: Pro tip: there's no need to add "please help me" and "thanks in advance" (or greetings, regards, signatures, etc). I've edited this sort of thing from your questions before - please read your edit notifications and see the sort of succinctness we like here. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you . I shall remember this for all my future questions.

Answer (score 1):

@Tarun if you are still facing the problem, then try restarting the tomcat and db servers. Make sure that there exists '**Thingworx**' folder under  `Tomcat install dir/webapps` folder, as upon successful installation Thingworx will automatically creates a folder over there.

Considering the **Thingworx** directory exists, try to access the apache tomcat's `catalina logs` and look for any errors at the End of File.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the browser cache? If this is a migration/upgrade, you may have a prior UI cached in your browser and it is conflicting with the version you are currently trying to install.

Additionally, checking the Security Log and Application Log for any warnings or errors may provide more insight into why the server is not loading Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and Thingworx related folders have  write permission of the user. Also, this can be caused of license problem. Make sure your license.bin file exists in ThingworxPlatform folder and platform-settings.json file is valid.

For further assistance, you can create a ticket from PTC Support.