# Thingworx Platform-settings.json file not connecting to azure Database

Tags: azure, thingworx, azure-postgresql

I am trying to connect the Thingworx 7.1 to Azure Postgresql database.

I have successfully able to point the the Thingworx Things to azure database without any error.

But when I am trying to set the database url inside the platform-settings file to point to azure database then I am getting the below error :

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to initialize and start system: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.thingworx.system.ThingWorxServer.loadModel(ThingWorxServer.java:448)
    at com.thingworx.system.ThingWorxServer.doHA(ThingWorxServer.java:181)
    at com.thingworx.system.ThingWorxBootstrapper.contextInitialized(ThingWorxBootstrapper.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  *** CRITICAL ERROR ON STARTUP: Unable to initialize and start system: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
  *** Web Application STATE is being set to ERROR! ***
```

Comment: A reminder of my [feedback here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48702011).

Comment: Have you checked the following link: https://community.ptc.com/t5/IoT-Tech-Tips/Frequently-Seen-Errors-upon-launching-the-ThingWorx-application/m-p/533607

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no error or typo in platform-settings.json and you are able to telnet db host & port from ThingWorx server/machine to test connectivity is fine.